# Printer misses file

Tags: printing, configure

How to solve the problem specified as:

> Printer state message is:
>   'File usr/lib/cups/backend/usb"not available: no such file or directory'.

Warnings are listed below:

> There is a missing print filter for printer 'Canon-TS8000-series'.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: My first question would be is cups installed with its dependencies and running: apt install cups; apt-get build-up cups; service start cups; service status cups, then are the PPD files installed ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is to the point, somehow the cups had been damaged. I suspect that it happened while I was trying to print photograph from the program "Digikam".

Meanwhile I have reinstalled cups and the problem was solved. So I can print. Stil have to try if printing from Digikam causes problems again. I do not blame the program as I may very well have chosen or filled out the wrong option before printing.
Thanks for your reply, Miel

Comment: This sounds *unlikely*. Printing something will **not** delete files.

Answer (score 0):

From Ubuntu 17.04, there is airprint support. It seems essentially all inkjet printers released in the last several years are supported; so it is likely this TS8000series was auto-set-up???? by ubuntu for you. If you right-click on the icon for this printer; that should be in the PRINTERS folder, it may say "driverless": this seems to show it is using the airprint mode. 
As an alternate, you can install the drivers Canon supply so go here https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_ts_series/pixma-ts8040.aspx?type=drivers&driverdetailid=tcm:13-1533040&os=Linux%20(64-bit)&language=EN and download and **SAVE** what will be  **cnijfilter2-5.40-1-deb.tar.gz** and it should end up in your **Downloads** folder. 
Open a terminal; copy each command below; paste into the terminal; hit the ENTER key after each line is pasted ..

```
cd Downloads
tar -zxvf cnijfilter2-5.40-1-deb.tar.gz
cd cnijfilter2-5.40-1-deb
sudo ./install.sh
```

the last command runs the install script; that should do all for you; please watch the terminal, as it may ask you questions

If you do install these drivers; the icon should have a slightly different name to your existing one: it would be useful for others to know; if the printing is different between the two; good luck